# StAX does not retrieve attribute's data

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax, stax

for the belwo posted xml file, i am using StAX to process it. i wote the below code, but i do not know why there are no info about the attribute are printed despite there are attributes in the xml file.
i expected the console to show info about "id" and "lat" and "lon" attributes

**coed**:

```
        for (int event = parser.next(); event != XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT; event = parser.next()) {

        switch (event) {
        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "@START_ELEMENT");
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getLocalName(): "+parser.getLocalName());
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getAttributeCount(): "+parser.getAttributeCount());
            break;

        case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
            //Log.d(TAG, "main", "@CHARACTERS");
            //Log.d(TAG, "main", "getTextLength(): "+parser.getTextLength());
            break;

        case XMLStreamConstants.ATTRIBUTE:
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "@ATTRIBUTE");
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getText():"+parser.getText());
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getAttributeCount(): "+parser.getAttributeCount());
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getAttributeCount(): "+parser.getAttributeLocalName(0));
            break;

        case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "@END_ELEMENT");
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getText():"+parser.getLocalName());
            break;
        }

    }
```

**xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<osm>
<node id="25779111" lat="53.0334062" lon="8.8461545"/>
<node id="25779112" lat="53.0338904" lon="8.846314"/>
<node id="25779119" lat="53.0337395" lon="8.8489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
<ele k="maxspeed:zone" v="60"/>
<node id="25779114" lat="53.334062" lon="8.841545"/>
<node id="25779117" lat="53.338904" lon="8.84614"/>
<node id="25779110" lat="53.33795" lon="8.489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="32"/>
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="no"/>
</osm>
```

**output**:

```
1: D: MainClass -> main: @START_ELEMENT
2: D: MainClass -> main: getLocalName(): osm
3: D: MainClass -> main: getAttributeCount(): 0
4: D: MainClass -> main: @START_ELEMENT
5: D: MainClass -> main: getLocalName(): node
6: D: MainClass -> main: getAttributeCount(): 3
7: D: MainClass -> main: @END_ELEMENT
8: D: MainClass -> main: getText():node
9: D: MainClass -> main: @START_ELEMENT
10: D: MainClass -> main: getLocalName(): node
11: D: MainClass -> main: getAttributeCount(): 3
12: D: MainClass -> main: @END_ELEMENT
13: D: MainClass -> main: getText():node
14: D: MainClass -> main: @START_ELEMENT
15: D: MainClass -> main: getLocalName(): node
16: D: MainClass -> main: getAttributeCount(): 3
17: D: MainClass -> main: @END_ELEMENT
18: D: MainClass -> main: getText():node
...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's normal: Look at the javadoc of [javax.xml.stream.events.Attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/events/Attribute.html):

> Attributes are reported as a set of events accessible from a StartElement. Other applications may report Attributes as first-order events, for example as the results of an XPath expression.

So, you have to read the attributes from the `START_ELEMENT` case.